# How i insert data into a database table using some jsp page?

Tags: jsp

Sir i make a database table name registration. i keep hsc roll, hsc year, hsc board, hsc group, SSC roll, ssc year,board, ssc group,name, contact number,qouta, gpa. i make some jsp page.In tha first page i want to insert HSC roll, hsc year,hsc group,hsc board, ssc roll, ssc year, ssc group, ssc board. After submitting these, in the 2nd page I want to insert name, contact number, qouta, gpa . After submitting this i want to insert unit name through 3rd jsp page. How i insert data in one table in database using this three jsp page? please help me ....

Answer (score 0):

NO, you can not do this. When you try to insert some values in your database you have to write the following query as like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES('','','','');
```

If your database table has four column and you want to insert value only in two columns you have to write the following query

```
insert into table_name values('first_value','second_value','','');
```

you have to make blank the other two columns by putting ('').
If you write the query as "insert into table_name values('first_value','second_value');"
there will be an error as like"Column count doesn't match value count at row_number".

Comment: thanks, if i could not do it. if i create three table for insert data using three jsp page. Could i retrieve all the data in one jsp page ??

Comment: Yes.you can get.